# Unterschied zwischen "nötigen" und "zwingen"

Tags: meaning, difference

Ich wüsste gerne den Unterschied zwischen "nötigen" und "zwingen".

> Er hat sie gezwungen, die Papiere zu unterschreiben.
>   Er nötigte sie, das Papier zu unterschreiben.
>
> Er zwang uns zum Bleiben.
>   Er nötigte uns zum Bleiben.

Answer (score 5):

Da gibt es eine ganze Anzahl von Unterschieden:

1. *Nötigung* ist ein Straftatbestand - *Zwang* nicht. Das Finanzamt kann dich *zwingen* deine Steuern zu bezahlen, aber nicht dazu *nötigen*. Man kann daraus also (zumindestens in diesem Kontext) ableiten, das *Zwang* u.U. mit einer Legitimation einhergeht, *Nötigung* nicht. *Nötigung* findet statt, wenn man jemand anderen ohne Legitimation seinem Willen unterwirft.
2. Außerhalb dieses juristischen Kontexts ist es eigentlich genau andersherum: Wenn meine Freundin mich *nötigt*, die Rechnung im Restaurant bezahlen zu dürfen, ist das zwar nicht notwendigerweise nett, aber auch nicht schlimm (es ist eher als eine stark ausgeprägte Bitte zu verstehen) - *zwingt* sie mich aber dazu, ist das ganz bestimmt nicht nett zu verstehen und hört sich an, als ob sie mich mit der Waffe bedroht hätte.

Die Wortherkunft von *nötigen*, abstammend von *nötig* hat eher etwas von "jemanden davon überzeugen, dass etwas nötig ist", während "Zwang" von alters her eher der Obrigkeit vorbehalten ist (siehe "[Zwingburg](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zwingburg)", "[Dresdner Zwinger](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zwinger_(Dresden))"). *Zwang* ist, wenn es mit der notwendigen Legitimation (Macht, Gesetz,...) ausgestattet ist, eine akzeptable Aktion, *Nötigung* kann grundsätzlich keine Legitimation haben.

Duden definiert 3 Bedeutungen für *nötigen*:

> (1) jemanden gegen seinen Willen (mithilfe von Gewalt, Drohung o. Ä.) zu etwas veranlassen; zwingen
>
> (2) (von einem Sachverhalt, Umstand o. Ä.) jemanden zu einem bestimmten Verhalten, Tun o. Ä. zwingen
>
> (3) durch eindringliches Zureden, Auffordern, Ermuntern zu etwas [zu] veranlassen [suchen], jemanden durch Zureden [zu] veranlassen [suchen], sich an einen bestimmten Ort zu begeben

Das Beispiel mit der Restaurantrechnung fällt ziemlich sicher unter (3), die schwächste Form des Nötigens.

Comment: Ehm, ist es überhaupt möglich, jemanden **nötigen**, etwas machen **zu dürfen**?

Comment: @Eller Du meinst das Beispiel mit der Freundin? Natürlich.

Comment: Ich meine, man kann jemanden nötigen zu bezahlen. Aber nötigen bezahlen zu dürfen??? Das ergibt keinen Sinn. Entweder man darf, oder man darf nicht. Es ist nicht möglich, jemanden zu nötigen ein Recht oder Erlaubnis zu haben. PS. Ich verstehe schon, dass "bezahlen zu dürfen" ein Eu­phe­mis­mus für "bezahlen" oder "bezahlen müssen" ist.

Comment: @Eller Siehe mein Edit. Natürlich wird mich meine Freundin nicht nötigen, bezahlen zu *dürfen* (das "darf" sie ja immer), sondern mich dazu bringen, *zuzulassen*, dass sie bezahlt. Das läuft aber im Prinzip auf dasselbe hinaus.

Comment: Nein, das Beispiel mit Rechnung fällt nicht unter 3. Wenn ich bezahlen darf, dann kann ich bezahlen, muss es aber nicht. Im Beispiel geht es aber genau darum, dass jemand "durch eindringliches Zureden, Auffordern, Ermuntern" veranlasst wird die Rechnung zu **bezahlen** und nicht zu **Recht haben**, eine Rechnung zu bezahlen. Vergleichen Sie mit "können". Es ist nicht möglich, jemanden nötigen, fliegen **zu können**. Nötigen **zu fliegen** - ja. Aber wenn man fliegen nicht kann, dann bringt eine solche Nötigung gar nichts - man fällt trotzdem auf den Boden.

Comment: _nach dem Edit des Kommentars_ Nun verstehe ich nicht ganz: den Text in der Antwort verstehe ich so, dass **Sie** die Rechnung bezahlen müssen. Aus dem Kommentar folgt, dass **Ihre Freundin** die Rechnung bezahlen möchte. Habe ich die Antwort falsch interpretiert?

Comment: @Ellern Meine Freundin *möchte* die Rechnung bezahlen. Ich sage, "das gehört sich nicht, der Mann bezahlt". Sie überredet mich, zuzulassen, dass sie bezahlt (weil z.B. mein Geburtstag ist). Sie *hat mich genötigt, die Rechnung bezahlen zu dürfen*

Comment: Ok, ich habe das andersrum verstanden.

Answer (score 1):

Im allgemeinen Sprachgebrauch sehe ich zwischen *»zwingen«* und *»nötigen«* folgenden Unterschied:

> **(1)** Beim Zwingen sorge ich dafür, dass jemand etwas tut, was ich will.
>
> **(2)** Beim Nötigen veranlasse ich jemanden zu einer Handlung, die meine
> Absicht sein *kann*, aber nicht *muss*.

Beispiele:

> **(1)** Ich zücke ein Messer und sage: »Mädchen, du ziehst dich jetzt
> aus.«
>
> **(2)** Durch mein Fahrverhalten sieht sich ein Autofahrer genötigt, in den Graben zu fahren, um eine Kollision zu vermeiden.

Comment: Sehe ich nicht so. In Beispiel (2) ließe sich beispielsweise genausogut "gezwungen" statt "genötigt" verwenden, und sogar die Aussage "Durch mein Fahrverhalten zwinge ich einen Autofahrer, in den Graben zu fahren, um eine Kollision zu vermeiden." wäre gleichbedeutend in Bezug auf das Verhalten des Sprechers.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper: _»Zwingen«_ und _»sich gezwungen sehen«_ unterscheiden sich. In Beispiel (2) war es nicht die Absicht des Sprechers, den Autofahrer in den Graben zu befördern, letzterer glaubte vielmehr, keine andere Wahl zu haben. Und wenn wir das Fehlen der Absicht voraussetzen, sollte in deinem Beispielsatz um der Klarheit willen _»zwinge«_ durch _»nötige«_ ersetzt werden, weil es sich um eine Nötigung handelt.

Comment: "Der Regen *zwang mich*, den Schirm aufzuspannen" vs. "Der Regen *nötigte mich*, den Schirm aufzuspannen" - **Wollte** der Regen in einem der beiden Fälle, dass ich den Schirm benutze?

Comment: @tofro: In meiner Antwort beziehe ich mich nur auf Personen.

Comment: @Pollitzer: "Und wenn wir das Fehlen der Absicht voraussetzen, sollte in deinem Beispielsatz um der Klarheit willen _»zwinge«_ durch _»nötige«_ ersetzt werden, weil es sich um eine Nötigung handelt." - wie gesagt, genau das sehe ich nicht so. Und zudem habe ich aufgezeigt, dass "zwingen" und "sich gezwungen sehen" effektiv dasselbe bedeuten können und beide keine Absicht voraussetzen.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper: Von _»zwingen«_ zu sprechen, wenn keine Absicht im Spiel ist, halte ich für ein Vergreifen im Wort. _»Ich habe ihn gezwungen, in den Graben zu fahren.«_ Das passt doch nur, wenn ich mit gezogener Pistole auf dem Beifahrersitz sitze.

Comment: @Pollitzer: Exakt dasselbe lässt sich aber auch bei der Aussage "Ich habe ihn genötigt, in den Graben zu fahren." anmerken.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper: Finde ich nicht, dein Satz ist auch verwendbar, wenn die Absicht fehlt. Nämlich in diesem Sinne: _»Ich habe ihn (durch mein Fahrverhalten) genötigt, in den Graben zu fahren. Er hätte auch sonst etwas machen können, nun gut, er hat sich für den Graben entschieden, wie sich gezeigt hat. Meine Absicht war das nicht, die Art seines Verhaltens habe ich ihm selbst überlassen.«_

Comment: @Pollitzer: "_»Ich habe ihn (durch mein Fahrverhalten) genötigt, in den Graben zu fahren.«_" - wiederum sehe ich keinerlei Bedeutungsunterschied zu "Ich habe ihn (durch mein Fahrverhalten) gezwungen, in den Graben zu fahren." Offenbar sehen wir das wohl einfach unterschiedlich.